# Want to return a list of members

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following objects

```
public class Club
{
    private List<Person> _Members = new List<Person>();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Members
    {
        get { return _Members; }
        set { _Members = value; }
    }
}
```

Now I have a `List<Club>` named clubsList and I want to generate a `List<Person>` that should contain a list of unique members.

For example, John Smith may be a member of Club A and Club B so he'll be in the Members list for both clubs. However, I want John Smith in my list only once.

I'm trying to generate this list using LINQ and I'd appreciate some help with it.

```
var uniqueMembers = clubsList.Select(x => x.Members).ToList()...???
```

Comment: You don't need to declare private member. You can simply do: `public List<Person> Members { get; set; } = new List<Person>();`, if you use VS 2015 or initialize it in constructor.

Comment: I suggest removing `set;` in the `public List<Person> Members`

Comment: Thanks Yeldar. I'll do that. Dmitry, why should I remove set?

Comment: @Sam: usually, you don't want to replace entire collection. You either want to add/remove collection members, or clear collection and populate it with new members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SelectMany` and `Disctinct` is a way to go:

```
clubsList
    .SelectMany(_ => _.Members)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

but to force distinct to work properly, you may want an overload with [equality comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), because by default `Distinct` compares references for reference types, and I don't know, how `Club.Members` are being populated

(I assume, that you don't want to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `Person`).